# How to have preset data in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a micro enterprise application. Within the application is a model class `Accounts`, which consists of a set of `Expense`, `Income`, `Assets` and `Liability` accounts. The only attributes set to the DB are `name`, `number` and `type`. I would like to have a full set of accounts preloaded each time a user signs up instead of them creating their own.

What would be the best way to have a set of preloaded accounts for each user that signs up?

Comment: you can use filters / callbacks for this.

Comment: What are the criteria that determine what is 'best'?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to seed the data in the db and when the user signs up it will show to them.

Other way would be to create a callback after the user signs up that will assign the set of accounts to that particular user.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your default values of  Expense, Income, Assets and Liability accounts into a yaml file, if you don't want to store them in the db. Than you can load them with a method you call on initialize, so the data is presented when a user signs up.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  after_initialize :read_defaults

  ...

  def read_defaults
    ...
```